# Pandas get row names (sample names) from Multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

suppose a dataframe which has an index like this one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,1],['A','B','C','A'],['a','b','a','b']]).T,columns=['d1','d2','type','subtype'])
df.set_index(['type', 'subtype','d1']).unstack('d1')
```

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,1],['A','B','C','A'],['a','b','a','b']]).T,columns=['d1','d2','type','subtype'])
df = df.set_index(['type', 'subtype','d1']).unstack('d1')
df.index

MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a', 'b']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 1, 0]],
           names=['type', 'subtype'])
```

I do use the values of the dataframe for some analysis (e.g. PCA). Aftewards, I would like to plot the results and name the points according to the index. I know the information of the row names is provided by the levels and the labels in the multiindex. How can I produce a list which gives me the names of each sample (e.g. ['Aa', 'Ab', 'Bb', 'Ca']) ?

Do I really have to do this ?:

```
l1 = df.index.get_level_values(0).values.tolist()
l2 = df.index.get_level_values(1).values.tolist()
[i1 + i2 for i1, i2 in zip(l1,l2)]
```

Which produces me:

```
['Aa', 'Ab', 'Bb', 'Ca']
```

Or is there a more elegant solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map`:

```
df.index = df.index.map(''.join)
print (df)
      d2                  
d1     1     2     3     4
Aa     4  None  None  None
Ab  None  None  None     1
Bb  None     5  None  None
Ca  None  None     6  None
```

Or list comprehension:

```
df.index = [''.join(idx) for idx in df.index]
print (df)
      d2                  
d1     1     2     3     4
Aa     4  None  None  None
Ab  None  None  None     1
Bb  None     5  None  None
Ca  None  None     6  None
```

Solution with [`str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df.index = df.index.to_series().str.join('')
print (df)
      d2                  
d1     1     2     3     4
Aa     4  None  None  None
Ab  None  None  None     1
Bb  None     5  None  None
Ca  None  None     6  None
```